# Need Macro for finding text inside the cell using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need a macro OR Formula to find the alphabets in the cell,kindly do the needfull.

Input        Output
521.03S          S
522.05KS         KS
520.32-EXS      -EXS
03.200.01-ABC   -ABC

i have to sort out the alphepets and "-"(Hypens) in excell.

looking for your answers....

Comment: Going to need a little more than that, also if you have tagged VBA you should try some code and post what you have tried in here first. Could you perhaps provide a screenshot of the data and the expected result?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

There's probably many ways to achieve this.  Here's a simple, brute-force method, that's easy to modify.  Though technically, it doesn't find the alpha characters, it makes the digits go away.

```
Function noNumbers(ByVal cltext As String) As String

Dim mytext As String
mytext = Replace(cltext, "0", "")
mytext = Replace(mytext, "1", "")
mytext = Replace(mytext, "2", "")
mytext = Replace(mytext, "3", "")
mytext = Replace(mytext, "4", "")
mytext = Replace(mytext, "5", "")
mytext = Replace(mytext, "6", "")
mytext = Replace(mytext, "7", "")
mytext = Replace(mytext, "8", "")
mytext = Replace(mytext, "9", "")
noNumbers = mytext

End Function
```